# How to we make a react native project as library project and use in another react native application

Tags: javascript, react-native, shared-libraries

We have developed some components( Custom textinput) and used in Project. As this text input component need for all other projects in company we want to make this textinput as separate library and link to another project

I could see that we can make as private npm module, but we need to buy account, **so looking for any another way it allows to link textinput component project in another project?. Please suggest**

Comment: You can use https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules

Comment: @Konstantin can you give more info, in that link it is just git documentation.

Comment: Any news on this question? Did you go with submodules?

Comment: How can we create such library please suggest

Answer (score 0):

Create it as public or private Node module by doing the following steps:

1- **create package.json file in your root directory** (the textInput folder) using this command

> npm init

it will ask you for some informations ,Provide responses for the required fields (name and version), as well as the main field:
name: The name of your module.
version: The initial module version.

2-**Create the file that will be loaded when your module is required by another application**
In the file, add a function as a property of the exports object. This will make the function available to other code:

```
exports.printMsg = function() {
  console.log("This is a message from the demo package");
}
```

3- **Publish your package to npm** :
For private packages and unscoped packages, use npm publish.
For scoped public packages, use npm publish --access public

4- **Download your package** in any project you want and use it

> npm install your-module-name

For more info please check the offical [Docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/creating-node-js-modules)

**Edit:** if you don't want to buy an account [Check this out](https://andreybleme.com/2020-05-31/hosting-private-npm-packages-for-free/)

Comment: due to money constraint i am not interested to go via private repo and public repo is exposed to all which i dont want because it is company component. So i need to some kind of mechanism to link one project to another

Comment: try using Haul ,check this topic: https://medium.com/javascript-in-plain-english/import-local-packages-in-react-native-using-npm-link-and-haul-d6b2fae313a3

Comment: I have checked above, above is working only if we install from android studio,If we generate release apk then app crashing. One more is it is not working in iOS

Answer (score 0):

The link I've included in my comment describes the process of creating submodules, but I might as well explain to you in what it consists.

Git submodules let you integrate some components as if they were separate modules (or packages). For example, in the project I'm working at we currently have around 7 submodules, and one of them is `Input` too.

I am not gonna enter in specific details as you can find them in the link I'm sharing, but generally speaking:

- You create your submodule as a separate repo on Github.
- This submodule is integrated into your project as if it was an npm package, albeit the difference is that the submodules should still be included in your `src` folder (we created a separate folder for the submodules we're using).
- Any time you want to modify your submodule, you modify it externally and then `update` it in your project. In your `git status` updates you're gonna see that it just updates the commit number, without presenting you all of the underlying code changes.

Generally speaking, submodules are thought to be quite complex, but once you get used to them - there is nothing too hard.

If you have any specific questions don't hesitate to continue the discussion.

Links:

1. Git [link](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules) on technical stuff of how to set up the submodules
2. Blog [post](https://github.blog/2016-02-01-working-with-submodules/) which in an easy manner explains how to use them
3. Another [post](https://chrisjean.com/git-submodules-adding-using-removing-and-updating/) on how to do actions on submodules